# How to handle broken packages related to different versions of nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, package-management

[That's the error I got when Im trying to install nvidia driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZonU.png)
As shown in the picture I have held broken packages.
''' sudo apt autoremove''' didnt help.
broken packages are related to different versions of nvidia driver

Comment: Remove the previous NVIDIA driver first.  Make sure to run `sudo apt autoremove` after removing the driver.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

First we need to do this:

'''sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver | awk '{print $2}')'''

then

'''sudo apt autormove'''